# VsCode pushing my different projects to the same repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I've been battling with this for a while.. I need your help.. I'm working on different projects on my hp laptop when I create a new project folder in VScode it uses the same repository as the previous ones. I have 3 projects and when I push all the commits from the 3 projects goes to the same GitHub repository, any idea on what I'm doing wrong please... I've read many things online but I'm just getting more confused

Comment: At a guess, you're creating all your projects as new folders inside an existing repository.

Comment: Well, maybe but how can I change that?

Comment: You were correct thanks... My .git folder for was in the same folder I created all my other projects.. That's why but after placing it in the respective folder... I stop having the above issues

Answer (score 1):

*Git* has never heard of a "solution" and has no idea what a "solution" is.  Git stores *commits* (which in turn store files), and a repository is a collection of *commits*.

A *solution*, in Microsoft-speak, is something containing one or more *projects*.  I'm basing this answer on the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), which you should probably read instead of this answer, especially since I don't use Visual Studio and have zero experience with projects or solutions.  Still, I'll put this answer up and see what sort of corrections I get.  [The best way to find the right answer on the internet is, after all, to proclaim the wrong answer, and then withstand the resulting flames.](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Concretely, a project is, apparently, simply a folder containing files.  If this is correct——then you can insert any number of projects into a Git repository, since a top-level folder in a Git commit can hold sub-folders, each of which could be a project.  The folder seems to become a project if it contains a `.csproj` file.  These files contain XML data, which Git merges very poorly, so do not allow Git to merge `.csproj` files across branches.

A *solution*, according to this same web page, is a *container for one or more products*.  Concretely, a solution is stored in a *solution file*, which is a regular or hidden file whose name ends in `.sln` or `.suo`.  VS apparently creates and manages this file itself and you are not supposed to edit it yourself.

Putting this together, then, you will want to:

1. create a new, empty folder and run `git init` in it;
2. use VS to create the "solution folder" and the `.sln` or `.suo` file;
3. create one or more projects within this location.

It's not clear to me whether you can just have a single project in a single top level folder without creating a sub-folder first, but it seems that VS manages this stuff for you.

Remember, Git just manages the commits, which then contain files.  Git has no idea whether `foo.csproj` or `bar.sln` is special in any way.  Git is just going to commit the file, or not, based on whether you've told Git to copy the working tree file into Git's index / staging-area and/or whether it was already in Git's index / staging-area from a previous commit.  Each commit contains a full snapshot of *every* file that was in Git's index / staging-area at the time you ran `git commit`.  Extracting a commit—with `git checkout` or `git switch`—fills in your working tree *from* that commit: whatever files are in the commit are now in your working tree.<sup>1</sup>  If some program or system takes some of those files to be "projects" and/or "solutions", that's the other program's business: Git is indifferent here.  Git is merely saving files in commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm deliberately glossing over a lot of special cases here.  For some of the gory details, see, e.g., [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).