# Create two projects (library and a project which uses it) in vs code which each have their own GitHub repository

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-git

I am using vscode on macos and want to create a persistence library and an Azure Function which uses it. I am stuck on how to structure this solution given the goals which are:

- Create a persistence library which can be used as a Nuget package hosted as a private GitHub package and used in other projects.
- During development I would like to be able to update both of them as I will be developing the library along with the Azure function
- During the release of the Azure Function, I would like it to use the package which would be built as a NuGet package and hosted as a private GitHub package

I know there are a number of steps involved in the Nuget part of this, but I am looking for how to structure the projects and solution so they end up in different repositories.

I saw this post, [VsCode pushing my different projects to the same repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73436138/vscode-pushing-my-different-projects-to-the-same-repository), which covers a similar topic, but not what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is a text editor and as such has no concept of projects.  There are ways to add the functionality via packages.  Are you looking for recommendations or to be told it just can't do it out of the box?

Comment: Create a Multi Root Workspace, each sub folder can have its own Git repo

Comment: @TimothyH, I can create projects like a class library by using a `dotnet new classlib` command and I can edit it in vs code. I can also create a function project as well and edit it in vs code. My question was how to organize them so they could be mapped to two different github repositories so one of them could be reused. The packages, I think, can be created using GitHub workflows and can be published in GitHub which can then be consumed by a dotnet project. I honestly think everything I'm asking is possible, I was just having trouble with this specific step.

Comment: Honestly, I use vim, my workflow keeps changing due to personal stupidity, but it's just about always the same workflow in different locations. Folder/project/simple/main.code etc or Folder/project/complex/subprojecta(/main.code)|subprojectb(/lib.code)... In this way everything together and each project (or subproject as it were), is it's own subdirectory... Major deviations from this have mostly been emacs related.

Comment: Honestly, in that way it's not even a text-editor specific thing... Am I missing something?

Comment: I use the source control ui and wanted to do so here with both project. I also didn't want a higher level project or sln file. I haven't done this before (referencing my own library from another project) and wasn't sure how to set it up. I think @rioV8 had the answer above. That's what I'm trying.

Comment: if a GUI can't do what you want, because not a lot of people need it, use a CLI command, always know the CLI commands you can use